# reading variables from input file bash

Tags: bash, file, input

I have an input file that looks like:

```
VAR1=1
VAR2=2 
VAR3=3
VAR4=.T.
```

I'd like to read in these variables and define them as such.  I've tried

```
 while read line
 do
  exec $line
 done < "Master.inp"
```

i've tried just

```
$line
```

instead, but that didn't work either.  Is there a way to run the string as if I had just typed out the string in the bash file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it just sourcing the code:

```
. file
```

this will let you use the vars `$VAR1`, `$VAR2`, ...

#### Test

```
$ cat a
VAR1=1
VAR2=2
VAR3=3
VAR4=.T.

$ cat b
. a

echo $VAR1
$ ./b
1
```

Comment: Excellent.  I love it when the solution is simpler than I expected.